# Cannot read property 'thisCompilation' of undefined in Visual Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Code. When I run the command 'ng serve' I get the below error:

[image]

This code is referring to a series of nodes and plugins that I had updated per a previous assignment that compiled without issue. Has anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: what's your webpack version?

Comment: Checked and I don't have the WebPack extension installed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling the latest webpack and cli. I then ran `ng serve` and it compiled successfully.

To remove the webpack:
`npm remove webpack`

To install:
`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 8):

I solved this with uninstall webpack and get the 3.11.0 version

```
npm remove webpack

npm install webpack@3.11.0
```

Comment: this one fixed my issue too.

Comment: I'm dealing with old project, i had same above error. this fixed mine one  too!(its a react project xd)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, made the same mistake of upgrading webpack independently.
This is how I was finally able to solve the issue:

```
npm remove webpack
npm install webpack@3.11.0
```

webpack's newest version (4.0.0) seems to be buggy